# Python Tkinter Treeview hierarchical data not shifted when I open a branch of the tree

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I'm having some troubles with treeview when I try to display hierarchical data. The desirable output would be the following:
[image: desirable output]

But my code is producing the following treeview:
[image: Closed branches]
[image: Open branches]

Please find below the relevant part of my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from ttkbootstrap import Style

root = Tk()
style = Style("superhero", master=root)
root.wm_iconbitmap(get_ico())
root.title('Alegység kezelyő')
root.geometry('700x650')

def machineQuery():
    for i in query_tree.get_children():
        query_tree.delete(i)
        root.update()

    conn = connectMe()
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT gepszam_id, azonosito, megnevezes FROM gep")
    records = cur.fetchall()
    print_records_id = ''
    print_records = ''

    for record in records:
        print_records_id = record[0]      
        print_records = '"' + str(record[2]) + '" "' + str(record[1]) + '"'
        query_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=print_records_id, values=print_records,open=False)

    conn.close()

def mainQuery():
    conn = connectMe()
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT gep_egyseg.gepszam_id, gep_egyseg.gepegyseg_id, gep_egyseg.egyseg_megnevezes FROM gep_egyseg JOIN gep ON gep_egyseg.gepszam_id = gep.gepszam_id")
    records = cur.fetchall()
    print(records)
    print_records_id = ''
    print_records = ''

    for record in records:
        print_records_id = record[1]      
        for_iid=str(record[0]) + "." + str(print_records_id)
        print_records = '"' + str(record[2]) + '" "' + ' ' + '"'        
        query_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=for_iid, values=print_records,open=False)
        query_tree.move(for_iid, record[0], END)

    conn.close()

def query():
    machineQuery()
    mainQuery()

query_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient = VERTICAL)
query_tree = ttk.Treeview(root, yscrollcommand = query_scrollbar.set)
query_scrollbar.configure(command = query_tree.yview)
query_scrollbar.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = NS)
query_tree['columns'] = ("Name", "Machine_id")

query_tree.column("#0", anchor = W, width = 20, stretch=NO)
query_tree.column("Machine_id", anchor = W, width = 100, minwidth = 50)
query_tree.column("Name", anchor=W, width = 150, minwidth = 75)

query_tree.heading("0", text = "  ")
query_tree.heading("Machine_id", text = "Gép azonosító")
query_tree.heading("Name", text = "Név")

query_tree.grid(row =3, column = 0, columnspan=2, sticky= NSEW)

query()

root.mainloop()
```

I know that it's just an aesthetic issue but it really bothers me.

Thank you for your help.

Edit:
A Version with some sample datas:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from ttkbootstrap import Style

root = Tk()
style = Style("superhero", master=root)
#root.wm_iconbitmap(get_ico())
root.title('Alegység kezelyő')
root.geometry('700x650')

def machineQuery():
    for i in query_tree.get_children():
        query_tree.delete(i)
        root.update()

    
    records = [(1, 'Some_uniqe_data1', "Machine1"), (15, 'Some_uniqe_data2', 'Machine2')]
    print_records_id = ''
    print_records = ''

    for record in records:
        print_records_id = record[0]      
        print_records = '"' + str(record[2]) + '" "' + str(record[1]) + '"'
        query_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=print_records_id, values=print_records,open=False)

def mainQuery():

    records = [(1, 1, 'Sub_component1'), (15, 2, 'Sub_component2'), (15, 3, 'Sub_component3')]
    print(records)
    print_records_id = ''
    print_records = ''

    for record in records:
        print_records_id = record[1]      
        for_iid=str(record[0]) + "." + str(print_records_id)
        print_records = '"' + str(record[2]) + '" "' + ' ' + '"'        
        query_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=for_iid, values=print_records,open=False)
        query_tree.move(for_iid, record[0], END)

def query():
    machineQuery()
    mainQuery()
    
query_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient = VERTICAL)
query_tree = ttk.Treeview(root, yscrollcommand = query_scrollbar.set)
query_scrollbar.configure(command = query_tree.yview)
query_scrollbar.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = NS)
query_tree['columns'] = ("Name", "Machine_id")

query_tree.column("#0", anchor = W, width = 20, stretch=NO)
query_tree.column("Machine_id", anchor = W, width = 100, minwidth = 50)
query_tree.column("Name", anchor=W, width = 150, minwidth = 75)

query_tree.heading("0", text = "  ")
query_tree.heading("Machine_id", text = "Some_Unique_Datas")
query_tree.heading("Name", text = "Name")

query_tree.grid(row =3, column = 0, columnspan=2, sticky= NSEW)

query()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: would be great if you provided some sample data, we don't have the database you have

Comment: Added some thank you.

Comment: The treeview adds an indent before the subitems, but only in column #0 (the tree part). You have no text in this column so you don't see the indent. To get the desired output you could move the content of column "Name" into column #0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the provided data, I make the following changes:

- use column `#0` as the `Name` column
- use `record[0]` as the value of `parent` option inside `mainQuery()`

Below are the required changes:

```py
...

def machineQuery():
    for i in query_tree.get_children():
        query_tree.delete(i)

    # fields: machine_id, unique_data, machine_name
    records = [(1, 'Some_uniqe_data1', "Machine1"), (15, 'Some_uniqe_data2', 'Machine2')]
    for record in records:
        query_tree.insert(parent='', index=END, iid=record[0], text=record[2], values=record[1])

def mainQuery():
    # fields: machine_id, component_id, component_name
    records = [(1, 1, 'Sub_component1'), (15, 2, 'Sub_component2'), (15, 3, 'Sub_component3')]
    for record in records:
        query_tree.insert(parent=record[0], index=END, iid=f"{record[0]}.{record[1]}", text=record[2])

...

query_tree['columns'] = ['#1']

query_tree.column("#0", anchor=W, width=200, stretch=NO)
query_tree.column("#1", anchor=W, width=100, minwidth=50)

query_tree.heading("#0", text="Name", anchor=W)
query_tree.heading("#1", text="Some Unique Data", anchor=W)

...

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the string formating way too. I'm still in the process of learning some of the built in solutions for python.